# How to integrate auto login SMF forum in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, forum, smf

I am going to integrate smf forum v.2.0.9 in my cakephp 2.x. I am using SSI.php

I have a users table in cakephp and another table name smf_members. I have successfully registered by using CakePhp code.

I have also successfully login in forum but page not redirected to my login page.

My code:

**login.ctp**

```
$_SESSION['login_url']='http://mydomainname.com/login';
$_SESSION['logout_url']='http://mydomainname.com/logout';

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://mydomainname.com/forum/index.php?action=login2" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Emailid" />
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" placeholder="Password" />
</form>
```

Above code successfully login. But page not redirect it stay in the forum index.php page. After login I need redirect page to **http://mydomainname.com/login**

This file is working if i am writing in core

Code:

login.php

```
<?php
include('forum/SSI.php');
$_SESSION['login_url']='http://mydomainname.com/login';
$_SESSION['logout_url']='http://mydomainname.com/logout';

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION); //exit;
echo "</pre>"; */
ssi_login();
?>
```

Please share your knowledge.

Thanks
ChatFun

Comment: Please can you clarify exactly what your issue is? Which logins are working? i.e. can you login to your Cake app only from login.ctp? If you are logged into your Cake app should you be able to also be logged into your SMF app? Are smf_members also users (are these tables effectively mirrors?) Is you redirect working from either of your login pages? What is the exact behaviour you want?

Comment: Both CakePHP and smf forum login successfully but separated. I need both at a time with single login page.

Comment: Are you using the Cake AuthComponent?

Comment: Without Auth how can I login cakephp? I am using AuthComponent.

Comment: Just wanted to check whether you have written your own login process. Is the SMF login process provided as part of the script or did you write it?

Comment: Please chck this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830485/smf-forum-session-not-working-inside-the-cakephp-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research finally i got one solution.

I have created external php file within webroot folder

i write following code in external_login.php-

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])){
session_start();
//include('forum/SSI.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Redirecting...</title>

</head>

<body>
<div style="display:block; position:relative">
<div style="position:absolute; left:-200px;">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo 'forum/index.php?action=login2';?>" method="post" name="smf_login_frm" id="smf_login_frm">
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" width="1" style="width:1px;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['email'];?>" />
<input type="password" id="passwrd" name="passwrd" style="width:1px;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['passwd'];?>" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ validateSubscription(); }, 1000);

function validateSubscription() {
        //document.smf_login_frm.submit();
        document.getElementById("smf_login_frm").submit();
        return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
include('forum/SSI.php');

global $context, $txt, $scripturl;
    $redirect_to = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login';
    $_SESSION['logout_url'] = $redirect_to;

    header('location:'.$scripturl . '?action=logout;' . $context['session_var'] . '=' . $context['session_id']);
    //$link = '<a href="' . $scripturl . '?action=logout;' . $context['session_var'] . '=' . $context['session_id'] . '">' . $txt['logout'] . '</a>';
    //echo $link;


}else{

}?>
```

First i have successfully login cakephp. then i will redirect to external_login.php. There i am getting my cakephp login session. So i assign username  and password then again i will redirect to smf forum login page. After successfully smf forum login page again redirected to Cakephp home page if i both are login successfully.

login action in UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
            $this->redirect($this->webroot);
        } else {
            $this->layout = 'login';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $data=$this->request->data;
                $this->Session->write('passwd',$data['User']['password']);
                if (!$this->Auth->login()) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Email or Password was incorrect.'), 'error_message');
                }
            }
            if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
                $this->redirect($this->webroot . 'external_login.php?login&hash_token='.md5(time()));
                exit;
                /*if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.type') == 1) {
                    $this->redirect($this->webroot . 'users/index');
                    exit;
                }
                if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.type') == 2 || $this->Session->read('Auth.User.type') == 3) {
                    $this->redirect($this->webroot . 'myprofile');
                    exit;
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am new to cakephp .

u have used action="http://mydomainname.com/forum/index.php?action=login2" method="post"

?action=login2 it is like get method your trying to use

try changing method=get
or
remove action=login2
save it in a hidden html element as u r using post

igonre if i was wrong